# What does "during the week" exactly mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, time

Many questions ask like "What time do you get up during the week/on the weekend," which makes "during the week" mean "from Monday to Friday." Does "during the week" exactly mean "from Monday to Friday"?

Comment: You'll have to know the context. If I say, "During the week, I have to stay sober so I don't get fired, but during the weekend, I can get drunk." then I'm talking about the work week, Monday to Friday. If I say, "During the week before Christmas, the malls are crowded." I'm talking about the seven days before the holiday.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was actually asking about the first context. And I can see your answer is yes as to if "during the week" refers to "Monday to Friday" when compared with "weekend." "Work week" comes up several times when I did searching online. I see where "during the week" probably came from.

Comment: Native speakers don't have to think about all the extra, non-linguistic knowledge that goes into understanding their language, but there's quite a bit.

Comment: The use of “work week” or “working week” doesn’t necessarily pre-date the use of just “week” to refer to the same thing. After all the whole idea of “weeks vs. weekends” arose together during (following?) the industrial revolution. I think of “working week” as just a way to be more specific and to remove the ambiguity when the context requires you to.

Comment: Thanks, Orbital Aussie. You're right. It's too fast for me to jump to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Longman Dictionary says

the part of the week when you go to work, usually from Monday to Friday **SYN working week**
a 35-hour week
during the week
I don’t see her during the week.